# Routing select hosts through vpn

Tags: linux, vpn, iptables, routing

I have a PPTP VPN connection set up on an ubuntu 8.10 box as ppp0 and I was wonder how to route select connections to go through the VPN.

For example I want google.com to go through the default interface, but bing.com to route through ppp0.

Could I do this with a routing rule? Or is something like this more cut out for iptables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using a routing rule but you will have to add all ip-addresses of bing to the route through ppp0.
In the real world this is much harder. Google for example has a lot of ips and is even getting more. So you will have to update your rule to reflect the addresses currently used.

Comment: The bing and google are just examples, the hosts i will be using only have 1 ip. What would adding a route rule like this look like?

Comment: this can be done by doing "route add -host <ip> gw <pp0 ip>"

Comment: You could also use "ip route add $IP dev $DEVICE"

Answer (score 0):

> Firefox -> Foxyproxy (filtering on regex) -> HTTP proxy -> VPN interface.

This sounds like you need to access webpages that are blocked on your subnet. 
If you have a machine outside this subnet with an ssh server, the easiest way 
is just to use the -D [port] option which gives you SOCKS. (putty can do this as well, 
if you're on windows.)  Then you just make foxyproxy redirect to the given port as socks5.

I realise this is old, but probably shows up in searches and I used to work in a place
with annoying restrictions.